# Ionic ngfor with custom key in json

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hello I have the below json in ionic application
Update
I change it to get an array from api and I get the following

```
{
"chest": {
    "chest": {
        "1": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "3": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
        ]
    },
    "hints": {
        "1": [
            "test1"
        ],
        "3": [
            "test2"
        ]
    }
},
```

How can I use to display the key and the value
I try the below

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let chest of workout.data.chest;let i=index" (click)="openNew(new.id)" detail-push >

<b> {{ chest}} </b> <br>
```

```
  <span *ngFor="let exercise of chest.chest |keys ">   
  <span *ngFor="let hints of chest.hints |keys ">        
  Machine: {{exercise.key}}, Days: {{exercise.value}}  
, Hints: {{hints.value}} <br>
```

I try above but I get in wrong place the hint and I get duplicate records

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. Firstly parse your Json object to array and then use that array with `*ngFor`.

Comment: ok I use Json parse and I get the below how can I use it with ngfor `{chest: {…}, hints: {…}}
chest
:
1
:
Array(2)
0
:
"1"
1
:
"2"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
3
:
Array(3)
0
:
"1"
1
:
"2"
2
:
"3"
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object
hints
:
1
:
Array(1)
0
:
"test1"
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
3
:
Array(1)
0
:
"test2"
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object`

Comment: you cannot use it. you should re-arrange your json to an array according your requirement.

Comment: how I can do than from my api or ionic?

Comment: it is better if you can do in api

Comment: i get array from api but I am still not able to print them in html

Comment: from postman `{
    "chest": {
        "chest": {
            "1": [
                "1",
                "2"
            ],
            "3": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"
            ]
        },
        "hints": {
            "1": [
                "test1"
            ],
            "3": [
                "test2"
            ]
        }
    },`

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
<div *ngIf="chest">

<ion-label color="danger" ><b>Chest</b></ion-label>
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row text-wrap>
        <ion-col width-25 >Exercises</ion-col>
        <ion-col width-25 >Machine ID</ion-col>
        <ion-col width-25 >Days</ion-col>
        <ion-col  width-25>Hints</ion-col>
      </ion-row> 
    <ion-row text-wrap *ngFor="let exercise of chest.chest |keys">
        <ng-container  *ngFor="let machine of MachinesDetails "> 
            <ng-container  *ngIf="machine.machine_no == exercise.key">

      <ion-col > {{machine.name}}</ion-col>
      <ion-col > {{machine.machine_no}}</ion-col>
    </ng-container >
    </ng-container >
      <ion-col > {{exercise.value}}</ion-col>
      <ng-container  *ngFor="let hints of chest.hints[exercise.key] |keys ">        
          <ion-col > {{hints.value}} </ion-col>
    </ng-container >
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```